# Zerotier: Why are ros2 talker and listerner working, but ros2 multicast is not

Tags: ros2, network, dds

Between an ubuntu server and my laptop is a zerotier network.

### Working:

Talker and listener are working when running them in a docker on both hosts:

```
me@laptop $ docker run --rm -it --net=host ros:rolling /bin/bash -c 'apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy ros-rolling-demo-nodes-cpp && source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash && ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener'
```

```
me@server $ docker run --rm -it --net=host ros:rolling /bin/bash -c 'apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy ros-rolling-demo-nodes-cpp && source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash && ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker'
```

Gives me:

```
[INFO] [1697051351.692214371] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 11]
etc
```

### Not working:

However, when debugging I noticed that this is not working:

```
me@laptop $ docker run --rm -it --net=host ros:rolling ros2 multicast receive
```

```
me@server $ docker run --rm -it --net=host ros:rolling ros2 multicast send
```

And nothing is being received.

### Notes:

- Wireshark on my laptop (zerotier interface) reveils the same: RSTP communication for the talker, nothing for the multicast send.
- Problem seems to be bi-directional

### Question:

Any ideas on how to debug this?